# Parsing functional application with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse expressions like the following using parsec:

```
f a b c
=> (Appl (Appl (Appl f a) b) c)
```

I tried using something along the lines of:

```
appl :: Parser Expr
appl = do
    f <- expr
    gs <- many expr
    return $ foldr (\x y -> Appl x y) f gs
```

but I am getting stuck in an infinite loop. expr is a function that parses all possible
expressions including whitespace obtained by creating a lexer (specifically using Parsec.Token.makeTokenParser).

I was wondering if there was some easy way to do this, or what others recommendations would be as to how to tackle this problem. I had considered trying to use Parsec.Expr, but I wasn't sure how I could use a space as an operator.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The definition of `expr` and `Expr` isn't included, so it is hard to say what is really happening. You should add those, and also a sample input and sample output. At first glance, and assume that `expr` doesn't consume whitespace, you need something like `sepBy expr spaces`, which will parse `expr`s separated by spaces.

Comment: I've commented a bit on expr, it consumes whitespace since it uses the tokens obtained from a lexer

Comment: Please include more of your grammar. Does the `expr` parser also parse `Appl`? If yes, then it's a case of [left recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) here.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is, as you suggest, to treat a spaces as a binary operator. First, define a parser for function application.

```
spacef :: Parser ()
spacef = whiteSpace
         *> notFollowedBy (choice . map reservedOp $ opNames)
         >> return Appl
```

Here reservedOp is the parser for reserved operators and opNames is a list of those names.  Now make this an operator in your grammar

```
functionOp :: Operator String () Identity Expr
functionOp = Infix spacef AssocLeft
```

and add functionOp to your table of operators that you use with `buildExpressionParser`, giving it a high priority.